Scroll to target horizontally with jQuery
Trying to revolutionize the world of carousels by creating something super simple and semantic that simply works with anchor links. It works mostly, but it jumps to the href rather than scrolling smoothly. What am I doing wrong here?
Edit: can't figure out how to include jQuery here, so here's a pen:
https://codepen.io/tactics/pen/xxNvYzV


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-+k1pnlgt4F1H8L7t3z95o3/KO+o78INEcXTbnoJQ/F2VqDVhWoaiVml/OEHv9HsVgxUaVW+IbiZPUJQfF/YxZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav a").click(function() {
    var $carousel = $('.carousel');
    var scrollTo = $(this).attr('href');
    // change its bg
    .css('background', '#9f3')
      // retrieve its position relative to its parent
      .position().left;
    console.log(scrollTo);
    // simply update the scroll of the carousel
    // $('.carousel').scrollLeft(scrollTo); 
    // use an animation to scroll to the destination
    $carousel
      .animate({
        'scrollLeft': scrollTo
      }, 500);
  });
});
</script>
.carousel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 770px;
}

.frame div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #39f;
}
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="frame">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
    <div id="d5"></div>
    <div id="d6"></div>
    <div id="d7"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<nav>
  <p><a href="#d1">1</a></p>
  <p><a href="#d6">6</a></p>
</nav>




so far all it does is Uncaught SyntaxError

That's not particularly helpful.

please read your question at this point: It works mostly (no it doesn't at all)

please take the time to make that snippet something close to what you described as mostly working so that it will be easier for someone to just pinpoint the actual issue you highlighted in your question about the smooth transition

it is mostly working as posted. Click the 1 or 6 links and the content scrolls to the appropriate anchor. It just doesn't do so smoothly.

OK, I see what you're saying. I have no idea how to add scripts to the sample here. I'll add a link to it elsewhere.

You can add the scroll-behavior attribute in your CSS
.carousel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


or using jquery:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav a").click(function() {
    var $carousel = $('.carousel');
    
    // selecting the target element to scroll to
    var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    
    // calculating the proper offset to scroll to
    var scrollTo = target.offset().left - $carousel.offset().left + $carousel.scrollLeft();
    
    // setting css
    target.css('background', '#9f3');

    $carousel
      .animate({
        'scrollLeft': scrollTo
      }, 500);
  });
});


Phenomenal! Thank you so much!
